# Poisson arrival times joint distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The arrival times of the first and second event are $S_1$ and $S_2$, and the number of arrivals follow a poisson process. How would I compute the Joint PDF of $S_1$ and $S_2$?

I have found the PDF of $S_1$ and $S_2$: $f_1(s)=\lambda e^{-\lambda s}$ and $f_2(s)=\lambda^2 se^{-\lambda s}$.

I also know the variables $S_1$ and $S_2-S_1$ are independent.

Comment: Sorry, I differentiated the CDF incorrectly, but I will correct the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also know the variables $S_1$ and $S_2-S_1$ are independent.

Yes, and thus: $$\begin{align}
f_{S_1,S_2}(s_1, s_2) & = f_{S_1, S_2-S_1}(s_1, s_2-s_1)
\\[1ex] & = f_{S_1}(s_1)\cdot f_{S_2-S_1}(s_2-s_1)
\end{align}$$

Now, do you know what $\;f_{S_2-S_1}(t)\;$ is?

Hint: A Poisson process is memoriless.

Comment: I am pretty sure: $f_{S_2-S_1}(t) = \lambda e^{-\lambda t}$. So would $f_{S_1,S_2}(s_1, s_2)=f_{S_1, S_2-S_1}(s_1, s_2-s_1)=\lambda^2 e^{-\lambda s_1}  e^{-\lambda (s_2-s_1)}=\lambda^2 e^{-\lambda s_2}$?

Comment: @TimothyHedgeworth Yes, indeed -- for $0 < s_1 < s_2$ ; it's $0$ elsewhere.